# How do I get Resharper to ignore the Designer file when navigating to a class?

Tags: resharper

In Resharper, if you ctrl-click the name of a class to naviate to its definition and that has a designer fie, Resharper will ask if I want to go to the X.cs or X.Designer.cs because the class is partial.

Does anyone know how to disable this annoyance so that it just goes to X.cs and ignores designer files?

Comment: Those are just plain C# files, how would a tool distinguish them?

Comment: Because they end in .Designer.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround I use is Ctrl-Shift-N (ReSharper classic bindings) or Ctrl-T (Visual Studio bindings) and start typing the class name. If you have your classes in files with the same name, you'll then be able to choose the correct one from the dropdown list.

Comment: Did you maybe mean Ctrl-Shift-T?  Ctrl-Shit-N does New Project on my machine.  Maybe it depends on what keystroke setup you choose for Resharper.

Comment: I wondered about this just after posting. I use the C# classic key bindings, compatible with older R# and IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: It's ctrl-t if you use the Visual Studio bindings.  If you update the answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.  Whenever I have a question like this, I file a suggestion at the ReSharper JIRA site.  I'd recommend you do the same.

http://www.jetbrains.net/jira/browse/RSRP

I don't believe you can do what you want at the moment, even with the latest nightly build.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to download the nightly build
i have no idea if they addressed this, although i think this is a feature, not an issue.

[Nightly Builds](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+4.5+Nightly+Builds)